# c++ base class object to call unknown methods in subclasses

Tags: c++, oop

I am facing this problem:

An upstream application defines a class (e.g. `box`), and a member (say `property`) with a base class type. I would make a derived class for that member, add new members and methods without updating their application.

Essentially I do `box->property = make_shared<myProperty>()`. Is there a way to keep the interface of calling the members and methods the same? That is, to access a property using `box->property->length` or `box->property->GetWeight()`, rather than `dynamic_pointer_cast<myProperty>(box->property)->GetWeight()`. The challenge here is they won't update the base `property` class, and I am not supposed to change `box`. But we wish to keep the interface the same so our customers won't complain.

Is it possible? If not, how could we do to best keep the main app and my plugin relatively independent while minimize the changes on the customer side? Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: You will have to use the typecast.

Comment: Why not wrap box in a template that has the actual type? You can avoid the casts that way.

Comment: Can change `property` from a base type to `myProperty` ?

Comment: I can't change the design of `box`. My code is considered add on to `box`. The `box` shouldn't depend on my code. @Taekahn  and @BBing

Comment: This is why I suggested wrapping the box. You aren’t changing it and it won’t depend on your code. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern

Comment: So you create a `myProperty` object in your code, and you access methods and attributes specific to `myProperty` in your code, but you are obliged to store a pointer to `myProperty` in an object controlled by foreign code, upcasted to `property`, such that methods and attributes specific to `myProperty` are not accessible from that place. Is that a correct assessment?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Exactly. Thanks for the precise description. How could I minimize the changes on the client side? i.e. keeping `box->property->GetWeight()`, rather than something like `_pointer_cast<myProperty>(box->property)->GetWeight()`.

Comment: @Taekahn Thanks. If possible I should use the box instance directly. After calling my API, clients might continue calling others' to add other properties to the same instance. So it's one starter API instantiate box, I add `myProperty` to it, others add `theirAttribute` to it, and so on. Could the clients still use `box->property->GetWeight()` as the property were implemented in the same place? Or is there something we could suggest to the "box" team for better design? The goal is to be able to develop the plugins separately. So we can add a new methods without other teams updating their code.

Comment: `box->property->GetWeight()` can't be done unless you modify the `property` class. It is dubious regardless, see [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter). And a cast is a sure sign of a broken design. The way out is to change one of the assumptions that I enumerated.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like the derived class for that member `property` violates Liskov's substitution principle.

You mentioned not being able to modify the `Box` class.
But are you allowed to modify the `property` base class? I suggest you add your "additional" methods of your derived class to the `property` base class.

The intent here being that the interface between the base and derived class should be one and the same. So do this only if it makes sense design wise.

Comment: Thanks @wyy. But no, I can only change the class derived from it.